# Getting error while deploying lightblue on WildFly 10.1.0

Tags: java, mongodb, deployment, maven-plugin, wildfly-10

[What is LightBlue?](https://github.com/lightblue-platform/lightblue-rest)

This is the error I am getting :

```
10:34:15,886 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.module.service."deployment.lightblue-rest-crud-basic-auth-2.10.0-SNAPSHOT.war".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service."deployment.lightblue-rest-crud-basic-auth-2.10.0-SNAPSHOT.war".main: WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.lightblue-rest-crud-basic-auth-2.10.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:91)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: com.redhat.lightblue:main
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1093)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1449)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1477)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:225)
    at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:68)
    ... 5 more

10:34:15,888 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 64) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "lightblue-rest-crud-basic-auth-2.10.0-SNAPSHOT.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.module.service.\"deployment.lightblue-rest-crud-basic-auth-2.10.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".main" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service.\"deployment.lightblue-rest-crud-basic-auth-2.10.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".main: WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.lightblue-rest-crud-basic-auth-2.10.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main
    Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: com.redhat.lightblue:main"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.module.service.\"deployment.lightblue-rest-crud-basic-auth-2.10.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".main"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
}
10:34:15,888 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 64) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "lightblue-rest-crud-basic-auth-2.10.0-SNAPSHOT.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.module.service.\"deployment.lightblue-rest-crud-basic-auth-2.10.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".main" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service.\"deployment.lightblue-rest-crud-basic-auth-2.10.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".main: WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.lightblue-rest-crud-basic-auth-2.10.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main
    Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: com.redhat.lightblue:main"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.module.service.\"deployment.lightblue-rest-crud-basic-auth-2.10.0-SNAPSHOT.war\".main"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
}
```

I have found some solutions that are telling me to add `module.xml` but I don't know exactly where to add that and what should be the content of `module.xml` for light blue.

I am very new in wildfly deployment it will great help if anyone comes up with a solution.

Does anyone with the same error as mine?

Comment: It looks like somewhere you're referencing a module called `com.redhat.lightblue`, but you haven't defined the module. Have a look at https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/Class+Loading+in+WildFly. You can install a module with the CLI `module add` command.